# Install and run lxde qt

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I am planning to install lubuntu 14.04 on a new partition. I am assuming that it runs lxde gtk.

How can I install lxde qt? Can both co-exist on the same partition?

How to switch between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions to install  lxde qt
It should be an option at login between the two

http://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/installing-the-lightweight-lxde-qt-desktop/